# Deserialize JSON List on wp7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I am trying to Deserialize a JSON api to c# on WP7. I need help in doing so. Im sure its an easy fix but i cannot just see it.

The JSON Data looks like this.

```
{
"chartDate" : 1349564400, 
"retrieved" : 1349816722, 
"entries" : 
[
    {
        "position" : 1, 
        "previousPosition" : 0, 
        "noWeeks" : 1, 
        "artist" : "Rihanna", 
        "title" : "Diamonds", 
        "change" : 
        {
            "direction" : "none",
            "amount" : 0,
            "actual" : 0
        }
    },
```

which translates to the following using http://json2csharp.com/

```
    public class Change
  {
      public string direction { get; set; }
      public int amount { get; set; }
      public int actual { get; set; }
  }

  public class Entry
  {
      public int position { get; set; }
      public int previousPosition { get; set; }
      public int noWeeks { get; set; }
      public string artist { get; set; }
      public string title { get; set; }
      public Change change { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootObject
  {
      public int chartDate { get; set; }
      public int retrieved { get; set; }
      public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
  }
```

In the application when i click the get feed button i am using the following code but it is coming back with the error **Cannot Deserilize JSON object into type "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Appname.RootObject**

The following is my C# from Mainpage.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Reactive;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonDemo
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var w = new SharpGIS.GZipWebClient();
  Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
    .Subscribe(r =>
    {
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
      PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized;
    });
  w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://apiurl.co.uk/labs/json/"));
}
```

}
}

Comment: u sure that r.EventArgs.Result contains the JSON

Comment: Yes, the results show. I think the problem is the .DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>> part but dont know how to fix it. This code was primarly taken from a sample which works fine but doesnt have the **public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }** in the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `r.EventArgs.Result` returns the (*correct*) json in question, this should work:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(r.EventArgs.Result);
```

**--EDIT--**

```
string json = @"{
    ""chartDate"": 1349564400,
    ""retrieved"": 1349816722,
    ""entries"": [{
        ""position"": 1,
        ""previousPosition"": 0,
        ""noWeeks"": 1,
        ""artist"": ""Rihanna"",
        ""title"": ""Diamonds"",
        ""change"": {
            ""direction"": ""none"",
            ""amount"": 0,
            ""actual"": 0
        }
    }]
    }";

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: @DeanMeehan I don't understand you. Using your class declarations, and after fixing your json in your question(it is invalid) above code works  well. See the edit.

Comment: Changing it to Root Object simply gives the error _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IObserver<Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.IEvent<System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>>' because it is not a delegate type_

Comment: The code does deserilize the content, but when i try and output the deserilized code on the next line _PhoneList.ItemsSource = deserialized;_ it comes up with the error because the JSON you gave is not a list

Comment: For you information the full JSON can be seen [here](http://ben-major.co.uk/labs/uk-top-40/)

Comment: No I don't need it. I am fed up with this conversation. Since you extend the question from deserialiation error to displaying it correctly.

Comment: nowhere did i say it was a deserialiation error. The problem is with the code where i cannot display the list from the deserilised JSON. Sorry you could not help

Comment: **nowhere?** From your question: `Cannot Deserilize JSON object into type "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Appname.RootObject`. :)))))